Using will and would in different context

When you visit me we will be playing games

when you visited me we would be playing games


I know that future continuous could refer to future plans. So, first example likely means "I am already in the middle of playing with someone else when you visit". Still, less likely but possible and correct meaning would be "it is my plan do play games after you arrive (with you not someone else)". Now, I know there is the difference between my examples 1 where "will" may imply a single event and 2 where "would" implies a habit or something repeated. So, could 2 like 1 have two possible meanings or does it work differently?

No, (2) does not  have two possible meanings.

@KateBunting do you agree with me that 1 could?

"When you visit me we will play games" means that we'll play after you arrive. Using the continuous form is wrong if that's what you mean. (There are a lot of similar questions here but I'm not checking to see if there is an exact duplicate.)

The examples are confusing, because as been pointed out, the most natural / likely meaning and way of expressing it is When you visit me we will play games - in which context we refers to speaker and addressee. But in the first example above, we must refer to speaker and unspecified other people. And the second example doesn't sound remotely natural to me anyway.

Meaning is created by context. None of the meanings you've suggested are contained in, or clear from, these sentences. In fact, when I first read #1, the valid meaning of "I'll be in the middle of playing with someone else" never occurred to me and I read it simply as a not-idiomatic way of expressing a future plan.

I suggest not asking about what sentences without context mean; instead, think of meanings and ask about the best way to express them. It's like asking what the symbol of a diamond means: It can mean different things in a poker game or on a ski slope. It doesn't actually contain its own meaning.

@Kate Bunting Why is that since 1 could?

I can't give a reason - it's 'just how English works'.  I would disagree with Stuart that the continuous is wrong - we do sometimes use it to state a plan for the future. "I'll be going to London next week."

I'll answer these "backward," in a way. Instead of looking at these sentences and asking whether they have certain meanings, let's look at those meanings and ask whether these sentences are good ways of expressing them. We have three different meanings discussed here:

When you arrive (in the future), I will be in the middle of playing games with some other person.
Let's plan that you and I will play games when, in the future, you visit me.
In the past, many times you visited me and we played games.

For meaning #1, one problem is the word "visit." A "visit" is rarely an instant in time; it's more often a length of time, if only a short one like an hour. You can make plans around it ("When you visit I'll bake a cake,") but it's hard to talk specifically about timing using it. Another verb like "when you arrive" would be a better choice.
Another simple problem is that, to use "we" to mean "myself and others, but not you," this group needs to be made very clear by immediately preceding context. It could work ("Hey, come over when you get off work tomorrow afternoon. Billy will already be there; when you arrive we'll probably be playing Mario Kart"), but if the context doesn't make it clear, it would be more likely to name the parties involved instead of saying "we."
For meaning number 2, future plans, "we will be playing" feels un-idiomatic when paired with a "when" time. True, progressive/continuous tenses can be used for plans ("Tomorrow we're baking cookies"—present continuous—or "Tomorrow we will be talking about chapter 4"—future continuous). I have a hard time putting my finger on why it's a poor fit here. It might be because "When you visit" is not a fixed point in time, or maybe because "playing games" is so vague as a "plan." At any rate, "When you visit we will play games" is a more idiomatic choice.
For meaning number 3, continuous tense is absolutely off the table. Talking about "habitual past actions" is an incredibly vague way of talking about the past to begin with ("When I was young I would get milkshakes at the drugstore": There is no indication of how many times or exactly how old I was), and continuous in past tenses is very specific about things happening at the same time ("I was reading when the alarm sounded": There is no indication how long I had been reading, but it is 100% certain that's what I was doing at that moment). I might try to imagine telling about past habitual actions, using "would," and finding a spot in that story that calls for continuous tense, but it feels like trying too hard to do something very unlikely.

I get that future continuous might be strange when I want to express the 2 meaning yet possible  and not out of question?
